# Is Sum of digits related with Sum of Squares of its digit

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In a specified range, I want to get the number of numbers, in which sum of its digits and sum of squares of its digits are prime number. For an example from `2` to `12`, there are only `2` numbers which has both its sum of digit and sum of square of its digit are prime number. These two numbers are `11` and `12`. In `12`, sum of its digit `1+2=3` and sum of square of its digit `1+4=5` are prime numbers.
Although the question is related to programming but it seems that there must be some number theory trick which can solve it quickly. I am very keen to know that trick if at all exists.
Thank you.

Comment: For your grammatical edification: "it's" is NOT possessive; "it's" is short for "it is", which is a complete sentence. "Its" is possessive, and should be used in every place you used "it's" here. (I could just edit, but "teach a man to fish...")

Comment: @TheChaz: Thank you for the information. i have corrected it. If anywhere you find any grammatical mistakes, please let me know. :)

Comment: The other two most common homophone mistakes are you're/your and they're/their/there.

Comment: Discussed as a programming problem at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8319/puzzle-sum-of-the-digits-is-prime-or-not

Answer (score 1):

Analytic number theory could produce a heuristic for *approximately* how many numbers up to $x$ satisfy your two conditions (that is, a predicted asymptotic formula), but I doubt it can be proved. Even if it could, it would only give the answer approximately, not exactly as you seem to want. So I don't think there's any trick besides a brute-force calculation.

Comment: Okay... thanks a ton.